# Clearing url variables

Tags: php

i am trying to sort out the error section of my settings page, and because i am validating all the data on a seperate script i have to use the url variables to check whether an error is present

so it looks like this if there is an error

localhost/site123675/settings.php?eid=1

however, the error shows fine, but i want a way to remove it, becuase if the user gets an error then enters a correct answer, it still shows the same error.

So, how can i clear the url of any variables before the user resubmits the page?

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your form's `action` set to? Or... can you show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what exact problem you're facing, but you could just do a header redirect:

```
if (isset($_GET['eid'])) {
    header('Location: /site123456/settings.php');
    exit;
}
```